# Jquery UI function on open working for the fist time but not for second time

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

With the Open attribute of a jquery ui dialog I am initializing two variables.

```
                      $('<div><b><center>'+ text +'</center></b></div>').dialog({
                            title: '<b>User(s) with a similar name</b>', 
                            modal: true,
                            autoOpen: true,
                            height: 400, 
                            width: 400,
                            resizable: false,
                            open: function() {
                                var show_per_page = 5;
                                var number_of_items = $('#all-tabs').children().size(); 
                                alert(number_of_items+' '+show_per_page);
                            },
                            buttons: {
                                "Close": function(){
                                    //alert($(this).attr('class'));
                                    number_of_items = 0;
                                    $(this).dialog('close');
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

But the dialog is holding the value returned by `$('#all-tabs').children().size()` for even after I am closing the dialog using the close button and the `$('#all-tabs').children().size()` should be different. I am having to refresh the page to reset the variables. How can I reset the variables and reinitialize them every time the dialog loads.

Comment: Are you aware that the `number_of_items` variable in the open function and the `number_of_items` variable in the close function are different variables? The one in the close function refers to a global variable, whereas the one in the open function refers to a variable that is local to that function.

Comment: No i was not aware. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code will recalculate the number of children each time the dialog is opened. I suspect that you only want the number of visible children, in which case try the following:

```
open: function() {
  var showPerPage = 5;
  var numberOfItems = $('#all-tabs').children(':visible').length; 
  console.log(numberOfItems + ' ' + showPerPage);
}
```